# Java arrays initializing after declare

Tags: java, arrays

I saw someone initialize and array like this in java

```
int[] s;

s = new int[]{ and put the list here..}
```

versus

```
int[] s = { the list here}
```

Are these both acceptable way of doing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, both are equally valid ways of creating a java integer array. The second version is just 
a shortcut syntax of the first version.

More on that here : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the latter is a shorthand for the former in a specific case: The latter can only be used directly in an initializer of a variable (where the type is given directly on the left-hand side), whereas the former can be used as an expression in general.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the **limitation** of using the shortcut syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the actual bytecode generated in both cases is exactly the same.